# Javascript 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?  From what I can tell buy documentation and whatever examples I can find, it should, but I keep getting the error below

```
var colorArray = [];
    colorArray[0] = [];
    colorArray[0][0] = '2F76EE';
    colorArray[0][1] = '2F76EE';
    colorArray[0][2] = '5fff74';
    colorArray[0][3] = '5e6cff';
    colorArray[0][4] = 'a6ff1d';
    colorArray[1][0] = '2F76EE'; //error is happening here
    colorArray[1][1] = '2F76EE';
    colorArray[1][2] = '5fff74';
    colorArray[1][3] = '5e6cff';
    colorArray[1][4] = 'a6ff1d';
```

The Error when I run it

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have two dimensional arrays. It has arrays, and you can nest them. But just because you put a sub-array in the first slot of the main array does not mean you automatically get one in the second slot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `colorArray[1][0]`, JavaScript accesses `colorArray[1]` and as it is not defined yet, it evaluates to `undefined`. So, you are trying to do `undefined[0]`. That is why it is failing.

To fix this,

1. you have to initialize element 1 like this

   ```
   colorArray[1] = [];
   ```

   before doing any changes to that element

   ```
   colorArray[1][0] = '2F76EE';
   colorArray[1][1] = '2F76EE';
   ...
   ```
2. Since you are doing static initialization, you can even do

   ```
   var colorArray = [];
   colorArray.push([ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d' ]);
   colorArray.push([ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d' ]);
   ```
3. Otherwise, you can initialize straight away, like this

   ```
   var colorArray = [[ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d' ],
                     [ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d' ]];
   ```
4. You can also do something like this

   ```
   var element1 = [ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d' ];
   var element2 = [ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d' ];
   var colorArray = [];
   colorArray.push(element1, element2);
   ```

   **Note:** You might be wondering, why I can't simply do

   ```
   colorArray.push(element1, element1);
   ```

   since both the arrays are the same. It will work, of course. But it has a problem. **If you mutate one of the arrays it will affect others** also. For example,

   ```
   var element1 = [ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d' ];
   var colorArray = [];
   colorArray.push(element1, element1);
   colorArray[0].push("abcdef");
   console.log(colorArray);
   // [ [ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d', 'abcdef' ],
   //   [ '2F76EE', '2F76EE', '5fff74', '5e6cff', 'a6ff1d', 'abcdef' ] ]
   ```

   You might not have expected this. But in JavaScript, all the variable names are just references to objects. So, when you do `colorArray.push(element1, element1);` you are adding the same reference twice. So, both the elements are pointing to the same object. So, mutating one will affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have

`colorArray[1] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

Far simpler than what you have, and also avoiding your problem:

```
var colorArray =
  [['2F76EE','2F76EE','5fff74','5e6cff','a6ff1d'],
   ['2F76EE','2F76EE','5fff74','5e6cff','a6ff1d']];
```

*(See other answers for why what you wrote is broken.)*